# Why does Angular 12 remove equal signs at the end of a url?

Tags: angular, angular12

I have this url `http://localhost:4200/info/NjFhYTgyOWZjODZkMDEwMDEyMDllYjUwOnByZTpubw==` but when a load my route, the equal signs disappear from the url and I need that token id (included equal sings) to call an API and get info.

This is the way how I get the url param but those equal signs are not there and the same time, they disappear from the url browser.

When I load the url in the browser, the equal signs disappear from the browser (it removes automatically from the url browser) and obviously, I can not get that equals params into my component.

***app-routing.nodule.ts***

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'survey',
    loadChildren: () => import('./survey/survey.module').then(m=>m.SurveyModule),
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

***survey.module.ts***

```
import { NgModule, ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { SurveyComponent } from './survey.component';
import { SurveyService } from './survey.service';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

const routes: Routes = [
    { path: ':id', component: SurveyComponent }
];

export const routing: ModuleWithProviders<SurveyModule> = RouterModule.forChild(routes);

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    SurveyComponent
  ],
  imports: [routing, HttpClientModule],
  providers: [SurveyService],
  
})
export class SurveyModule {}
```

***survey.component.ts***

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-survey',
  templateUrl: './survey.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./survey.component.scss']
})
export class SurveyComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    private _surveyService: SurveyService,
    private _route: ActivatedRoute,
  ) { }
  
  ngOnInit(): void {

    this._route.params.subscribe(params => {
      console.log(params) //log the entire params object
      console.log(encodeURIComponent(params['id'])) //log the value of id
    });
  }

}
```

any suggestion ..?

Comment: Please provide more details. What is the full url? What does that token represent? What did you do to navigate to this url?

Comment: I already edited it

Comment: Please provide how you are performing your navigation, I've tested this by passing that id using `router.navigate()` and it does not remove the `==`.

Comment: I'm guessing you are not using the `router` service or the `routerLink` property to navigate. You should use one of those since they will encode special characters. If you are navigating with something like an `<a></a>` tag you would need to encode `=` as `%3D`.

Comment: I'm not try to set a url and use router.navigate(), I'm trying to get a token from the url, but that token has == at the end of the url but Angular remove that == from the url automatically when I load the page with the url, and reload the page without those characters at the end of the url

Comment: Well how did the url get the token if you didn't navigate? If you use router.navigate() it will take care of special characters, even on reload

Comment: I think maybe you are typing the url in manually, or providing someone with an external link. In that case `=` is not a supported and the character must be encoded as `%3D`. ie change `NjFhYTgyOWZjODZkMDEwMDEyMDllYjUwOnByZTpubw== ` to `NjFhYTgyOWZjODZkMDEwMDEyMDllYjUwOnByZTpubw%3D%3D`

Answer (score 0):

If you try to set route as a string, then you need to escape `=` sign. That's because this character has a special meaning in the query string - it separates parameter name from its value. The semicolon `(";")` and equals `("=")` are reserved characters that are often used to delimit parameters and parameter values applicable to that segment.

You could use [encodeURIComponent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) to escape this behaviour.

```js
console.log(`?x=${encodeURIComponent('NjFhYTgyOWZjODZkMDEwMDEyMDllYjUwOnByZTpubw==')}`);
// expected output: "?x=NjFhYTgyOWZjODZkMDEwMDEyMDllYjUwOnByZTpubw%3D%3D"
```

Here are some examples how to encodeURI and params with Angular routing: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uri-encode-activated-route-param-7tqhha?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

To get the current url you would need to read the params

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-cars',
  templateUrl: './cars.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./cars.component.css'],
})
export class CarsComponent implements OnInit {
  survey: string;
  currentURL: string;
  currentURLDecoded: string;
  constructor(private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute) {
    let location = window.location;
    console.log(location);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.survey = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('survey'); // Snapshot param
    this.currentURL = this.router.url;

    this.router.events.subscribe((val) => {
      this.currentURL = this.router.url; // Update the value when a different route is accessed
      const lastPart = this.router.url.split('/').pop();
      this.currentURLDecoded = decodeURIComponent(lastPart);
    });
  }
}
```

```
Current URL: /info/NjFhYTgyOWZjODZkMDEwMDEyMDllYjUwOnByZTpubw%3D%3D
currentURLDecoded URL: NjFhYTgyOWZjODZkMDEwMDEyMDllYjUwOnByZTpubw==
```

Here is a working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-access-url-params-snapshot-bhmr6m?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcars%2Fcars.component.ts

Comment: Angular's `Router` service and `routerLink` attribute will automatically encode the `=` character.

Comment: I'm not try to set a url and use router.navigate(), I'm trying to get a token from the url, but that token has == at the end of the url but Angular remove that == from the url automatically when I load the page with the url, and reload the page without those characters at the end of the url

Comment: I see. I have included and example how to read params. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-access-url-params-snapshot-bhmr6m?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcars%2Fcars.component.ts

Comment: you are passing the url through routerLink, and is not my issue. My issue is that, I have a url that I try to access in the browser, and that url has equal character == at the end, so, those equal signs are removed automatically in the url browser by Angular.

Comment: Maybe is an issue of Angular Router ??

Comment: When you enter url with params and you have `==` at the end, the browser strips them. They never make it to Angular - this is not a problem with Angular. Try to visit my example and see that not even `window.location` can get the equals signs. Like I said, their special reserved special characters. Avoid navigation with such links. https://angular-access-url-params-snapshot-bhmr6m.stackblitz.io/info/NjFhYTgyOWZjODZkMDEwMDEyMDllYjUwOnByZTpubw==

Comment: yes, but at the same time, I found that if you do not use Router Module in Angular, and you use a single app in one page without routing, those special characters like == at the end of url are not removed by Angular in the Url browser. So, by the way, There is a issue opened in Angular Github about that https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/21381